# Laravel 8.55 with Fortify showing Class 'App\Providers\User' not found while login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, fortify, laravel-fortify

I have installed laravel 8.55.0 and installed fortify with it for the authentication handling. Registration is working fine and login also validation is working fine. but when I enter email and password (either right or wrong) it's displaying **Class 'App\Providers\User' not found** I checked all files but cannot find the problem, can you guys please suggest a good solution for the problem:

**Validation is working**
[image: fortify is handling the validation]

**Error**
[image: I am getting this error]

**The error says there is the problem with this line**
[image: error code]

Comment: Your code is trying to figure out what `User::` references. It guesses to the current Namespace (`App\Providers`), and can't find it there. Import it (via the answer below), or reference it directly like `App\Models\User::` in your code.

Comment: Now it's saying: Class 'App\Providers\Hash' not found

Comment: It's the same thing; it doesn't know what `Hash::` is referencing. If you get the same error, just pointing to a different thing, try to apply the same fix; it's generally the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider.php add this line:

```
use App\Models\User;
```

Comment: Now it's saying: 
Class 'App\Providers\Hash' not found

Comment: add this line too: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
and remember every class you use you have to import it with use syntax and the class path

Comment: Thanks friend. you solved my problem. many many thanks. :)